# Is there a norm $N$ such that the unit ball is not compact ? even not closed?

Tags: functional-analysis

Is there a normed space $(E,\|\cdot \|)$ such that the unit ball $$\{x\in E\mid \|x\|\leq 1\}$$ is not compact ? not closed ? I would say no, but it's a question of an exercise of mine (please not go in weak topology).

Answer (score 2):

The unit ball will always be closed: If $x$ is not in the unit ball because $\|x\|>1$, then the open ball of radius $\|x\|-1$ around $x$ is disjoint to the uint ball.

However, it is often not compact: Let $E$ be the space of bounded real sequences and $\|x\|=\sup\{\,|x_n|:n\in\Bbb N\,\}$.  Then the open balls of radius $\frac12$ around arbitrary centers cover the unit ball, but there is no finite subcover.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm unfortunately not allowed to prove the second point. But What could be a sequence of the unit ball that is not bounded in $\ell^\infty $ ?

Answer (score 2):

As Hagen von Eitzen points out, the unit ball $\{x\in E:\|x\|\leq 1\}$ is always closed, because the map $x\mapsto\|x\|$ is continuous, and $[0,1]$ is a closed subset of $[0,\infty)$.

But compactness is different.  The unit ball is compact if and only if $E$ is finite-dimensional.  This is a consequence of the [Riesz Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%27s_lemma), which can be used to inductively define a sequence in the unit sphere $\{x\in E:\|x\|=1\}$, a closed subset of the unit ball, which has to convergent subsequence.